# Filter by array of ids

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am planning to implement a search filter by array of ids. This array could have up to 1000 - 10000 ids. 
Is the recommended way to filter based on id´s like this?

```
$filter=Id eq 'ID1' or Id eq 'ID2'
```

Is this expensive performance vice?
Is this expensive price vice?

Comment: Can you provide more details about your scenario? Are you trying to implement document-level security with the filter, or something else...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to filter by that many IDs in a single query due to Azure Search's [filter size limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search#a-namebkmklimitsa-filter-size-limitations). If you were filtering by a few hundred IDs it would be possible, but thousands is definitely not going to work.

We are considering ways to relax the limit or provide [alternative mechanisms](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/13805454-get-documents-from-an-array-of-ids), but nothing will change in the near future.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, what is the limit in hundreds? 900? I want to query based on user favorite ids. Is this expensive in terms of price?

Comment: Price is based on dedicated capacity. No amount of capacity is going to get around the filter limit; They are unrelated concerns. The limit is not exact (it's based on the overall size and complexity of the query, not a specific number of clauses), but it's likely much closer to 300-400 than 900. You would need to impose this limit (or preferably a lower one) on your lists of user favorite IDs in order to make this work.